# unable to render HTML inside react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to run this component inside react native

```
<StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />
```

currently, I am using `react-native-render-html` package

and doing likewise

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";
import HTML from "react-native-render-html";
import StyledFirebaseAuth from "react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth";

const PhoneAuth = () => {
    const uiConfig = {
        signInFlow: "popup",
        signInOptions: [
            {
                provider: firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                recaptchaParameters: {
                    type: "image",
                    size: "invisible",
                    badge: "bottomleft",
                },

                defaultCountry: "+91",
                whitelistedCountries: ["IN", "+91"],
            },
        ],
        // callbacks: {
        //  signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function (authResult) {
        //      var user = authResult.user;
        //      const data = { phone: user.phoneNumber };
        //      props.setPhoneNumber(data);
        //  },
        // },
    };

    const htmlContent =  
        `<StyledFirebaseAuth uiConfig={uiConfig} firebaseAuth={firebase.auth()} />`
    
    return (
        <View>
            <HTML  html={htmlContent} />
        </View>
    );
};
export default PhoneAuth;
```

but as HTML content is a string it's not picking the variables
and I get a blank screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you're creating a custom HTML tag or element you have to tell the *renderers* to do so, i.e.:

```
const content = `<bluecircle></bluecircle>`;
...
 
renderers: {
    bluecircle: () => <View style={{ width: 20, height: 20, borderRadius: 10, backgroundColor: 'blue' }} />
}
```

You might try the following

```
import HTML from 'react-native-render-html'

...

render() {
    // The html you want to render
    const html = `
        <div>
        </div>
    `

    const styles = {}

    const renderers = {
        StyledFirebaseAuth: (htmlAttribs, children, passProps) => {
            return (
        <StyledFirebaseAuth
          {...passProps} />)
        }
    }

    return (
        <HTML
            // Required. The html snippet you want to render as a string
            html={html}

            // The styles to supply for each html tag. Default styles
            // are already pre-provided in HTMLStyles.js. The additional
            // styles that you provide will be merged over these, so if
            // you need some funky red background on your h1, just set
            // the background
            htmlStyles={styles}

            // Renderers to use for rendering specific HTML elements.
            // Default renderers are pre-provided in HTMLRenderers.js.
            renderers={renderers}
    )
}
```

See [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-render-html#creating-custom-renderers)

Comment: @SagarChavan have you provided `renderers` object to `HTML` ? if so this might be an element which cannot be rendered to mobile view, as mention in docs not everything in browser is render-able in mobile view

Comment: can you pls show in this code how should I add renders

Answer (score 0):

set style to view flex: 1 as showed in example

```
<ScrollView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <HTML
     html={htmlContent}
     imagesMaxWidth={Dimensions.get("window").width}
    />
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebView](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview) for this purpose. No need to use any other library.

```
<WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html: htmlContent }}   
/>
```

See [API reference](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#react-native-webview-api-reference) for more details.